# JS equivalent of <script> tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

This is how I load UI5 library within a html page.

```
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript'
    src='https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
    data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
    data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'>
</script>
```

As you see, we actually pass two attribute/value pairs here.

Now I need to load it within a JS code. This is because I need to use it within a context.js of a Chrome extension.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting? It would help JS newbies like me.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is a little unclear to me and that might be why others did. When you say you "need to load it within a JS code", do you mean accessing the two attribute/value pairs programmatically, like as variables?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mean , I want to simulate in JS what this script tag does.

Comment: Inserting a `<script>` element in the DOM would use no more resources than what you have here and is the best method. You can insert the element anywhere and it'll run (even after the page has loaded). The lesser recommended method is making an AJAX request to download the script file's contents yourself and running its code directly using `eval`. There are two problems with this... First in order to make an AJAX call, the file has to be on the same domain that the page came from. Second, using `eval` is [highly frowned upon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx).

Comment: Wait this is for running JS in a Chrome extension instead of a web page?

Comment: Yeah. That's right. To run on a js file on a chrome ext.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Specifically, "context.js of a Chrome extension" is meaningless, and so is "run[ning] on a js file".  Are you trying to use `sap-ui-core.js` as a content script, but want the attribute pairs?  Are you trying to programmatically inject the script, but want the attribute pairs?  Is your problem running the script, or having the attribute pairs, or both?

Answer (score 0):

To run JS in an extension, it's recommended that all the code be packaged with your extension. This is to prevent the possibility of user's browsers becoming compromised. This just requires downloading the JS file, packaging it with your extension, and updating your extension once newer version becomes available if so desired.

See here for the full documentation, including how to whitelist certain domains to use scripts from there: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading